# Qual è il senso di "attaccare" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nella commedia *Sotto paga! Non si paga!* di Dario Fo (testo aggiornato nel 2007 e pubblicato da Einaudi) ho letto:

> ANTONIA     
>   Guardi, signor brigadiere che lei sta prendendo
>   un granchio...
>   
>   BRIGADIERE     
>   No, il granchio l’ho preso prima... quando ci
>   sono cascato con la sceneggiata delle doglie e del parto
>   prematuro! Ma adesso non ci casco più, basta! Fuori la
>   refurtiva!
>   
>   ANTONIA     
>   Ma di che refurtiva parla? È impazzito?
>   
>   BRIGADIERE     
>   E non facciamo le furbe, che tanto non **attacca** più! Il giochetto ormai è scoperto! (*Cambia tono*) I mariti vanno fuori a fare razzia, poi passano i sacchetti alle
>   mogli che si fanno un pancione e via! È tutto il giorno
>   che vedo passare donne incinte! Ma possibile che tutte le femmine di ’sto quartiere siano rimaste in stato interessante allo stesso tempo? Che è? La maratona provinciale del sesso? Capisco la proverbiale prolificità delle
>   donne del popolo... ma qui si esagera! Donne mature, ragazze, ragazzine, perfino una vecchietta di ottant’anni
>   ho visto passare incinta oggi: un pancione che pareva
>   avesse due gemelli!

Non riesco a capire del tutto bene cosa vuol dire il brigadiere quando pronuncia le parole "non attacca più" in questo dialogo. Dal contesto sembrerebbe qualcosa come "non è più credibile", ma non sono sicura che questa sia l'interpretazione corretta di questa espressione. Ho cercato alla voce "attaccare" del *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* [qui](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI01/00000812.jpg), [qui](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI01/00000813.jpg) e [qui](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI01/00000814.jpg). Tuttavia, non so a quale accezione corrisponda l'uso che se ne fa nel passaggio sopra citato. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: "Non attacca" significa "non funziona".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'uso è piuttosto diffuso, come intuivi significa che chi parla non ha creduto a ciò che gli è stato raccontato. Dal [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/attaccare/) (voce 7):

> Molto com. l’uso fig.: *queste idee non attaccano*, non trovano terreno propizio alla loro diffusione; nell’uso fam.: *non attacca!*, a proposito di discorso, parole, proposte e sim. a cui non si vuole dare ascolto; anche in forme più esplicite e in costruzione personale: *accennò debolmente una proposta, ma vedendo che non attaccava, desistette; quando essa arrischiava timidamente qualche parola ... o non attaccava, o veniva corrisposta con uno sguardo distratto, o sprezzante, o severo* (Manzoni)